# Is there anyway to memset over a triple pointer?

Tags: c

For a variety of reasons I have a list of objects that I need passed around in the form of a triple pointer.  I declared it like so.

```
List=((Entity***) malloc(sizeof(Entity) * 32));
```

Every cycle of this list being passed around requires the entire list to be wiped which I attempted using the line below.

```
memset(&***List,0,sizeof(Entity) * 32);
```

The end result of that method is an Access violation error.  What can I do to get around this?

Comment: Iterate through the list freeing each element?

Comment: That would probably work but I'm wondering if there is a way to do the memset method.

Comment: `memset` can only set a contiguous block of memory. You haven't described how you have allocated memory so there is no way to answer this question.   Using `sizeof(Entity)` is almost certainly a bug however.

Comment: To get better help post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you are declaring a dynamically allocated three-dimensional array List[M][N][K], the correct way to initialize it is:

```
List = (Entity***)malloc(sizeof(Entity**) * M);
for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
    List[i] = (Entity**)malloc(sizeof(Entity*) * N);
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        List[i][j] = (Entity*)malloc(sizeof(Entity) * K);
        for (int k = 0; k < K; ++k) {
            memset(&List[i][j][k], 0, sizeof(Entity));
        }
    }
}
```

But suppose you are to initialize a statically allocated array like above, you should make M, N, K constants that can be determined at compile time and declare Entity List[M][N][K] directly. Thus you can initialize it as:

```
memset(List, 0, sizeof(Entity) * M * N * K);
```

Comment: @mahendiran.b Please note that the second code only applies to statically allocated situations (i.e., Entity List[M][N][K]; it's contentious) not the allocation using malloc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is mistake in your code. I like to explain with simple code

```
 int main(void){

 char ***List = NULL;
 List=malloc(sizeof(char **) * 32); //step1
 List[0]= malloc(sizeof(char *) * 32);//step2
 List[0][0]=malloc(sizeof(char) * 32);//step3
 memset(&List[0][0][0],0,sizeof(char) * 32); //step4

  return 0; 
}
```

After doing step1, you are trying to do step4. But there is step2&3 that you have missed. Which means you have allocated memory for 3D pointer only. Without allocating 1D memory memset is done for 1D pointer.